# How to access Tracking-URL from `yarn application -list`?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I want to see the yarn web UI for a certain job that I see in yarn.

when I do `yarn application -list` I can see the tracking URL `<tracking-URL>`.

So, I navigate to that page in chrome and it gives me an error like this:

```
The 172.12.15.181 page isn't working.
172.12.15.181 didn't send any data.
```

I'm clearly ssh'd into the machine that should allow me to see it.  Also, the job is definitely in `status=RUNNING` in YARN. So, what could be preventing me from seeing the yarn web UI at this url?

Am I doing this correctly?  thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Tracking URL showing in the yarn application --list is correct, the problem is you are not able to access it correctly.

1. Make sure that your computer is allowed to reach the node where spark's driver code is running , check the network firewall.
2. Make sure that the port is used for the URL is allowed from the firewall. If not use dynamic port forwarding.

   In most of the cases the unknown ports are blocked from the firewall end for security reasons ,and you need to do a dynamic for forwarding for viewing the URL.

I personally use putty and create dynamic port forwarding tunnels, and then use "SwitchySharp" chrome extension for viewing spark UI.

Comment: Thanks @RBanerjee.  I've definitely run spark applications in other clusters (by a simple ssh access) and I've had no trouble accessing the web UI just by clicking on the `Tracking URL`.  The spark jobs always start at port `4040` on other clusters, and on this one.  So, I'm wondering why this cluster isn't letting me access port 4040??  But it has definitely worked at other clusters.

Comment: Anyway, I'm willing to try dynamic port forwarding.  How would I set that up?

Comment: It's a difficult to explain here, Let me try, Login using putty, goto change settings-> Connection-> SSH->Tunnels ,Only Set Source port as 9999 Type Dynmic and Ipv4. then Apply. Now open mozilla, Setting-> Advance->Network Settings->Manual Proxy ->Only Set SocksHost as 127.0.0.1 and port as 9999 , Press OK. It should work , you can try SwitcySharp if you are using Chrome which is working better than mozilla, Try changing Socks version to v5 if doesn't work. Try googling to get more info on dynamic port forwarding.

Comment: Also the port is not always 4040, it will change dynamically if the 4040 is already occupied. So use correct port for opening the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
Open an SSH tunnel to your machine:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/<KEY_FILE>.pem -L 4040:localhost:4040 -N <USER>@<SERVER_PUBLIC_IP>
```

Step 2:
Visit `localhost:4040` in your browser.